# Windows 10 Display Scaling and PowerShell Forms

Tags: winforms, powershell, scaling

I really have a serious problem ... I developed a tool in PowerShell for our employees in the company for many years now. This tool has a graphical user interface done with PowerShell Forms. With PowerShell Forms I mean something like that here:

```
[void] [system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")

$window = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$window.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$window.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$window.AutoSize = $False
$window.MinimizeBox = $False
$window.MaximizeBox = $False
$window.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"
$window.Backcolor = "White"
$window.Text = "Caption of the Window, blah blah"
```

Code just should Show how I use PowerShell Forms. Normal method, I guess.

Everything works perfect so far. Now we received new notebook models and those notebooks have a display resolution of 2560×1440. Per default the display scaling of Windows 10 is set over 150% so users could see something on the tiny displays.

**This setting results in a very serious problem for me and my tool. All the graphical elements like buttons, labels, textboxes etc etc look incredible akward and displaced.**

Is there any chance to do something about that ???

If people set the display sacling at 100% Windows would be too small at this high resolution in combination with the small displays ...

Comment: What do you mean by PowerShell forms? You probably need to fix your code in order to handle the scaling correctly.

Comment: Hi there Seth, thanks for your comment. I edited my text above to show you how I use PowerShell Forms fur GUI. It is just a part of the code.

Comment: That does MWE have the display error you're talking about? Maybe have a look at [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx).